# Calculating time difference with time-numbered format

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to calculate time difference with the time being presented as number. For example:

```
8:00AM => 800
11:15AM => 1115
4:30PM => 1630
```

Now, calculating time difference between `8.30AM` and `10AM` should give `1.5`, but I'm unsure how it is best done.

I'm using JavaScript to calculate `(1000-830)/100` but it would return `1.7`

Comment: Well, 8:30AM is not 830 minutes after midnight. Get your times to hours or minutes, and calculate with those.

Comment: `830` to be exact. I understand what you mean but if you're forced to use that presentation of time, how would you calculate it?

Comment: Can't you represent that in minutes? 600 min for 10am

Comment: As I said, parse it into a different representation that allows the arithmetic you need.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some functions I prepared earlier

```js
var hhmmToMinutes = function (s) {
    var v = parseInt(s.replace(/\D+/g, ''), 10);
    if(s.indexOf(':') < 0) {
        v = v * 100
    }
    var isPm = s.toLowerCase().indexOf('pm') > 0;
    if (!isPm && ((v / 100) | 0) == 12) {
        v -= 1200;
    }
    return v % 100 + ((v / 100) | 0) * 60 + (isPm ? 720 : 0);
};
var hoursDiff = function(a, b) {
    return (hhmmToMinutes(a) - hhmmToMinutes(b)) / 60;
}
console.log(hhmmToMinutes('8:00AM'));
console.log(hhmmToMinutes('11:15AM'));
console.log(hhmmToMinutes('4:30PM'));
console.log(hhmmToMinutes('12:30AM'));
console.log(hoursDiff('10AM', '8:30AM'));
```

Comment: derp - yes, it does fail for that :p - to be honest the function "I prepared earlier" accepts only 24 hour format - my "quick fix" was inelegant - now fixed

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saying that your input format is already like `800`, `1115`, etc. If so, then I'd convert that to hours as decimals such that `1115` becomes `11.25`, and then just subtract the two times:

```js
function hoursSinceMidnight(t) {
  return Math.floor(t/100) + t % 100 / 60
}
  
function timeDiff(t1, t2) {
  return hoursSinceMidnight(t1) - hoursSinceMidnight(t2)
}

console.log(timeDiff(1000, 830))
console.log(timeDiff(1100, 800))
console.log(timeDiff(1330, 1015))
console.log(timeDiff(1015, 1330))
console.log(timeDiff('1330', '1015')) // works for string inputs too
console.log(timeDiff(1423, 701))
```

Use `Math.abs()` if you don't want negative answers. And note that the last example above resulted in a lot of decimal places - you didn't say if you wanted to round the answer to some maximum number of decimal places, but I'll leave that to you...

Answer (score 0):

I have never used any conversion like this but I think a very simple way to do this is

Convert 10.00 to 1000 i.e. multiply the time by 100
Similarly, convert the other number suppose 6.30 which will be 630

The difference between the two is 1000-630 = 370
Now to convert this before dividing it with 100 subtract the difference by 40

```
float convert(int time1, int time2)
{
   int diff = Math.abs(time1 - time2);
   diff = (diff-40)/100
   int multiplier = 100;
   double perc;  
   perc = (int)((diff - (int)diff) * multiplier);
   perc = perc/60;
   diff = (diff - (diff -(int) diff) + perc;
   return diff;
}
```

I don't know about any pre-defined function but this should work according to me.

Reason for subtracting 40 from the difference is that we should not consider values 61 - 100 i.e. 40 as minutes restart from 60

```
Now we have 1000-830 = 170 - 40 = 130/100 = 1.3
to convert 30 to minutes 1.3-1 = 0.3 *= 100 = 30 
Now we have 30/60 = 0.5 minutes
diff = 1.3 - (1.3 -1) + .5
diff = 1 + 0.5
diff = 1.5
```

I think this should work and help your understanding.